# Correct avoiding R/W file deadlock

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, deadlock

Python script create child process `proc = subprocess.Popen()` which write several lines to `p.txt` every ~1 second. I wanna to handle `p.txt` updates in this script real-time while `proc` is running.

```
...
def seek_file(file, process):
    while process.poll() is None:
        l = file.readline().strip()
        if not l:
            sleep(0.1)
            continue
        else:
            yield tuple(l.split('='))
...
p_file = open('p.txt')
data_tuples = seek_file(p_file, proc)
for d in data_tuples:
    print(d)
...
```

Why this code occasionally become to deadlock-state? What is the best way to process frequently updating files and display the progress?

Comment: I assume `yeild` is a typo?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is deadlocking, just spinning once it gets ahead of the process writing the file.

When you reach EOF in a file, the file object won't produce new lines even if the file subsequently grows. You can reset this behavior by doing an `f.seek(f.tell())`, as seeking (to the current position) will reset the EOF indicator.

Comment: Note: I can't rule out deadlock, but as written, it doesn't look like you're working with standard handles for the process; you can't actually "deadlock" on a normal file read (it either works or it hits EOF, it doesn't block waiting for the file to grow).

Comment: In most cases generator works fine for a long time. But once per week script is freezing at `seek_file` and stoping subprocess execution (updating `p.txt`).